# Call a function from the same `module.exports` object by it name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to call a function within the `module.export` object by knowing only it  `string` name

```
module.exports = {

  a : function() { console.log('a'); },

  b : function() { console.log('b'); },

  c : function() {
    var fn; // string contain the name of the function to call ('a' or 'b' for example)

    // How do I call `fn` programatically from here?
    // something like `self[fn]()`
  }

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it with the object name:

```js
var module = {
    exports: {
        a: function () { alert('a'); },
        b: function () { alert('b'); },
        c: function (fn) { // string contain the name of the function to call ('a' or 'b' for example)
            module.exports[fn]();
        }
    }
};
module.exports.c('b');
```

Comment: also you could do

```
module.exports = {
  a() {
    console.log('a')
  },
  b() {
    console.log('b')
  },
  c(fn) {
    fn()
  }
}
```

and in another file you call it like
var func = require('./func.js')
func.c(func.a)

Comment: @Jekrb, i do not understand.